# Java servlet can't recognize packages

Tags: java, apache, servlets, tomcat7

I have a Java servlet that calls to an API using Apache's various libraries. I have each of those JARs in the WEB-INF/lib directory, however when I compile my code in the WEB-INF/classes directory that holds my servlets, it shows:

```
GrooveAPICall.java:10: error: package org.apache.http does not exist
```

as well as for each of the other packages I tried to import. How can I import these packages for my servlet? Is there something I have to put in the web.xml file?

Comment: In other words, you simply didn't include those libraries in classpath during compile? How exactly are you compiling your servlet classes then? Consult the compilation tool's documentation how to specify the compiletime classpath. That specfic problem has actually nothing to do with servlets.

Comment: *If* they're actually being deployed then they should be available. If they're not on your *compile* path then they won't compile.

Comment: Are you using an IDE?  If so, just add the jars to the project's libraries in the IDE.

Comment: Yeah I have been compiling them calling javac -cp .:/usr/share/java/servlet-api-3.0.jar GrooveAPICall.java. I didn't know that WEB-INF/lib is not immediately accessible during compile-time. Would I have to list out each of the jars that I need within the javac statement in the Terminal?

Comment: Also, I don't use an IDE because of how Eclipse sets up the file directories, this project is on a private repository so I didn't really want to mess around with that.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a class in WEB-INF/classes or a jar in WEB-INF/lib makes them accessible at execution time. Not necessary at compilation time.

In other words, the execution classpath includes jars at WEB-INF/lib and classses at WEB-INF/classes, but the compilation classpath doesn't necessary do that.

Comment: As much as I complain about Maven in my profile, it resolves things like this for you if you have your projects set up properly (i.e. the web project has the other projects as dependencies). You just have to remember to declare any appserver-provided libraries (such as servlet-api) as a "provided" dependecy so it doesn't get packaged in the child's jar.

Comment: Gradle can do most of this as well, but it [doesn't have the provided dependency](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-784) for non-web projects.

Comment: Although Spring has [created a plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/gradle-plugins/tree/master/propdeps-plugin) to work around this deficiency in Gradle.